# importing from a different folder but on the same level as the file importing from in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my Python project I have the following folder hierarchy

```
/dir1/
     - mymodules/
            - oslib.py
     - scripts/  
            - rename.py
```

I'm trying to import stuff from "oslib.py" which is under "mymodules" folder,
from the file named "rename.py" which on the same level but different folder names "scripts"

in other posts the usage of sys.path.append was suggested and so I've tried:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
import mymodules.oslib
```

but get the following error:

> Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'mymodules'

I also tried:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../mymodules")
import oslib
```

and got:

> Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'oslib'

What am I doing wrong?

if relevant: I'm using python 3.6 and this is a windows machine

Comment: Where are you running your script from? `python3 rename.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have in **mymodules** directory the **__init__.py** file.
This file indicates that the directory is a python package.

You need also to add the path to **dir1** in  Python path, because python will look to mymodules in its path.

Comment: to my understanding, in Python 3.6 __init__.py file is not required.
the problem was I didn't not add dir1 to the path, as you mentioned and that solved it for me.
I change it to 'sys.path.append("../dir1/")' and 'from mymodules.oslib import *' and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
from mymodules import oslib
```

I tried to replicate your project's structure, it seemed to work for me.

[image]